# question about the paper "ADDITIVE LOGISTIC REGRESSION: A STATISTICAL VIEW OF BOOSTING"

Tags: logistic, boosting, likelihood

I am reading the paper "additive logistic regression:a statistical view of boosting". I am confused about how to get equation (31),(32),(33) in the paper. Could anyone explain a bit please?

equation (31): $E l(F+f)=E[2 y^*(F(x)+f(x))-log[1+e^{2(F(x)+f(x))}]]$.

equation (32), (32) are the first and second derivative of eq (31) at $f(x)=0$,respectively.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi: Someone will be more inclined to help if you point to a link where the paper can be obtained. If it can't be obtained, then you need to provide more details as far as the equations.

Comment: Hi. Thanks . I got the answer.